# Calculating pct_change on pandas Series with Decimal values raises unsupported operand type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series that i fill with Decimal values (random values in this case)

```
In [240]:  
s = pandas.Series([Decimal("423234.53463"),Decimal("4234.53463"),Decimal("4223434.53463"),Decimal("42654234.53463")])

In [241]: s
Out[241]:
0      423234.53463
1        4234.53463
2     4223434.53463
3    42654234.53463
dtype: object
```

and when I try to apply pct_change:

```
In [242]: s.pct_change()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-243-5c16731f0315> in <module>()
----> 1 s.pct_change()

/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in pct_change(self, periods, fill_method, limit, freq, **kwds)
   3665
   3666         rs = (data.div(data.shift(periods=periods, freq=freq,
-> 3667                                   axis=axis, **kwds)) - 1)
   3668         if freq is None:
   3669             mask = com.isnull(_values_from_object(self))

/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in flex_wrapper(self, other, level, fill_value, axis)
    676         self._get_axis_number(axis)
    677         if isinstance(other, pd.Series):
--> 678             return self._binop(other, op, level=level, fill_value=fill_value)
    679         elif isinstance(other, (pa.Array, pd.Series, list, tuple)):
    680             if len(other) != len(self):

/Users/mike/.virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _binop(self, other, func, level, fill_value)
   1452             other_vals[other_mask & mask] = fill_value
   1453
-> 1454         result = func(this_vals, other_vals)
   1455         name = _maybe_match_name(self, other)
   1456         return self._constructor(result, index=new_index).__finalize__(self)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

Initial search did not return any similar problems, except [this issue on pandas github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/737)

I have considered using

```
s = s.astype(float)
```

but I would like to see some solution before sacrificing precision with float.

Comment: you can do `ts.diff().div(ts.shift(1))`

Comment: using Decimal is not efficient at all; unless you really really need fixed precision you should use floats

Comment: @behzad.nouri Damn... so simple and it worked... It seems really strange that pct_change does not have some sort of option

Comment: @Jeff I want to work with financial data so I am not sure if I should trust floats... I understand the inefficiency of Decimals but the amount of data is not enough to make a huge difference.

Comment: @MakisTsantekidis I usually use an int64 mills (1/1000th of a dollar) for money.

Comment: question: the pandas documentation is very bad and I cannot figure out - does pct_change return a fraction or actual percent change. i.e - if the change is 50% - does it return 50 or 0.5?

Comment: It returns a ftaction, in your example that would be 0.5